# Maven tomcat7-maven-plugin not found error

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven, maven-3

I am new to working with Maven. Searched alot but no success. Tried my best. Someone explain to me what to do to fix this issue. Any of your current pom with struts2 and tomcat 7 will be very helpful.

I am using maven3

**ERROR**

*Plugin 'org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT' not found*

I see this plugin is available at http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository/org/apache/tomcat/ . Got link from here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/maven-jars.html#Using_Tomcat_libraries_With_Maven

**My pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Struts2_Maven_Web</groupId>
    <artifactId>Struts2_Maven_Web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Struts2_Maven_Web Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


    <build>
        <finalName>Struts2_Maven_Web</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>


</project>
```

**EDITED************

I just found version 2.0 and its resolved fine.

*Should I use this. Difference between 2.0 and 2.0-SNAPSHOT. Anyone? .*

```
 <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the version **2.0**, without the SNAPSHOT.

This is because the plugin was released on the 10th of September, and, as far as I have seen, when a plugin or dependency is released, the snapshot versions are removed from the repositories.